# Copy a file and create a directory if it doesn't exist in PHP

Tags: php

I need simple PHP code to copy a file and create the directory if it doesn't exist (PHP).

Example:

```
$f1 = "x.txt";
$f2 = "a/b.txt";
mycopy($f1, $f2);
```

My copy should make sure the folder exists (i.e., create it if necessary) and copy the file.

My attempt:

```
function mycopy($s1, $s2) {
    $path = pathinfo($s2);
    if (!file_exists($path['dirname'])) {
        mkdir($path['dirname'], 0777, true);
    }
    if (!copy($s1, $s2)) {
        echo "copy failed \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```
function mycopy($s1, $s2) {
    $path = pathinfo($s2);
    if (!file_exists($path['dirname'])) {
        mkdir($path['dirname'], 0777, true);
    }
    if (!copy($s1, $s2)) {
        echo "copy failed \n";
    }
}
```